# Can we set a route path's name dynamically?

Tags: angular, routes

I'm creating a school management system in angular and i wanted the route path name to be assigned dynamically, so that each schools will have their own URL for login. For Example: when a school is created by the super-admin, a mail with a link to login will be sent the school's admin. (which will be something like: "xxx.yyy.schools/school1", xxx.yyy.schools/school2,xxx.yyy.schools/school3 ). The email link will have to be generated like the above mentioned examples as school 1, 2 and 3.

I have searched the internet and found solutions for adding up route path names as children by using 
{path ':schoolname', component: SchoolLoginComponent}, but that's not what i'm expecting

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'school1',component: LoginComponent},

The above is what i have tried but the path name is set to be static as "school1", where i want it to be generated dynamically with the name of the school.

I have a school creation form that sends a mail to the school's admin with the link to URL, but that's assigned statically. I want the route path name to be dynamic, so that the school's admin could realise that the URl can only be used by them

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't set `pathname` dynamically, Angular compiler needs to know about your `pathname`s AOT.

BUT, a better approach will be, set path param dynamically for example

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'schools/:id',
    component: LoginComponent
  }
]
```

you can use `:name` instead of `:id` if it makes more sense for you, and navigation will be something like that

```
<!-- from HTML -->
<a routerLink="/schools/{{id}}">Crisis School</a>
```

or

```
// from component.ts
this.router.navigate(["schools", id]);
```

Here's an in action [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dummy-angular-school-managment-system), notice that in this example the school URL will be `yourdomain/schools/school-name`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ahmed, but I'm not looking for a click event to change the URL, I wanted to generate a URL once the school is created. and this URL is going to be used by the user to login

Comment: @krishie I've added an example check it out.

Comment: you can solve your problem by generating the school id in your server and append it in your domain name then integrate this answer

Comment: I'm getting routed to the schools when we login from the app, but I wanna know how do we do it when a link is sent to the user and the user uses that particular link to login